Camlocks, hoses and convention
CONCLUSION: F/F Hoses as they are likely to to be dragged on the ground and the mating surfaces are protected. You can get M/M adapters to connect F/F hoses together for extra length.  Males are 1/3rd of the price and most are likely to use the same hose and have many more males on things like tanks and pumps.
I'm upgrading some water tank outlets with camlock fittings.
I was wondering what the conventions are, if any, regarding what gender of camlock should go where.
I would have to assume having male and female on hoses would be useful as I could connect them together to get a longer length, but I've also seen female/female hoses before and it would seem easier to remember that all other connections that aren't hoses, should be male.
Any other considerations? I think the male fittings are much cheaper and perhaps more tolerant to being out in the dust and rain?
Thanks!

Female female hoses (with the lock levers) are the norm for me. I use adapters for extension. This way I don't have to be picky about which side of hose I pick. Also having these female ends against a wall or tank would make it difficult to handle the levers.

Also protects the mating surface if you're dragging it along the ground. I think f/f hoses are the way to go and I'll just use a small m/m adapter if I need to string them together. Thanks

Please put your cumulative findings and reasoning into an answer and accept it as correct.

F/F Hoses as they are likely to to be dragged on the ground and the mating surfaces are protected. You can get M/M adapters to connect F/F hoses together for extra length. Males are 1/3rd of the price and most are likely to use the same hose and have many more males on things like tanks and pumps.
